# React Native, construct initial state values from a object or array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, object, state

Is it possible to create states in the constructor passed to that component from an array or object.

Here is what is to be achieved:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        Object.keys(this.props.data).map((key, i) => {
            [key]: 'boo',
        })
    }
}
```

but it returns a syntax error.

The idea is that the data within `this.props.data` creates a series of states. The data passed to `this.props.data` is not known by the component in advance but is passed to it as a prop when the component is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could directly declare `this.state` with return array of map

**updated**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mapData = Object.keys(this.props.data).map((key, i) =>({[key]: 'boo'}))
    this.state = this.pre_state ? Object.assign({}, ...this.pre_state) : {};
}
```

Comment: However, the state is not accessible. Calling this.state.WhateverTheKeyWas returns as undefined.

Comment: Sorry . this.state only accept as object . i just updated my answer .You could use `Object.assign` for creating array to object .sample eg https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-cdn-pr6td